# Overwriting a file when compiling g++

Tags: c++, g++

If I have a c++ file and compile it but then have to make changes, I have to remove the file and recompile. It is not a huge inconvenience but I would rather not have to do that every time I test a program. Do any of you know how to overwrite a file when compiling to it?

Comment: Usually g++ can overwrite output files by simply specifying existing files as output. That sounds like your antivirus software is bothering you.

Comment: I believe overwriting is the default behavior. Could you give a hypothetical example with your command lines attached?

Comment: Are there some obstacles from your computer environment that prevent you from overwriting? Or is it just your (or your school's, your office's, your teacher's, your boss's, etc.) rule? It looks like some more explanation is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you shouldn't have to delete it, just recompiling will replace the old executable with the new one.